# Draw2d text types not correctly displayed in a ui-bootstrap accordion angularjs app

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, draw2d, draw2d-js

I am trying to use `draw2d` javascript library inside an `ui-bootstrap-tpls` accordion inside an `angularjs` application.

A simple example: (I would build a plunker, but I am unable to include the required libraries.  In this example, `draw2d-canvas` is implemented as an angularjs directive.

index.html:

```
<body id="myBody" ng-controller="MyDrawCtlr">
<div class="col-xs-12 panel panel-default row">
    <div id="canvas1" draw2d-canvas></div>
        <uib-accordion close-others="true" class="col-xs-8">
           <uib-accordion-group heading="The Chart" is-open="true">
               <div id="canvas2" draw2d-canvas></div>
           </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js: (Taken from the angularjs template delivered as part of the draw2d package)

```
var app = angular.module('test2dApp', ['draw2d', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MyDrawCtlr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.jsonDocument1 =
        [
            {
                "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle",
                "id": "rec1",
                "x": 50,
                "y": 100,
                "width": 201,
                "height": 82,
                "radius": 5,
                "resizeable": true,
                "selectable": true
            },
            {
                "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Label",
                "text": "This is a label.",
                "id": "myLabel1",
                "x": 50,
                "y": 50,
                "minWidth": 100,
                "fontSize": 30,
                "padding": 200,
                "resizeable": true,
                "selectable": true,
                "cssClass": "draw2d_shape_basic_Label"
            }
        ];
});

var d2 = angular.module('draw2d', []);

d2.directive("draw2dCanvas", ["$window", "$parse", "$timeout", function ($window, $parse, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E,A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.editor = $.extend(true, {
                canvas: {
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 1000
                },
                palette: {
                    figures: []
                },
                selection: {
                    className: null,
                    figure: null,
                    attr: null
                }
            }, scope.editor);
            var canvas = new draw2d.Canvas(element.attr("id"), scope.editor.canvas.width, scope.editor.canvas.height);
            canvas.setScrollArea("#" + element.attr("id"));
            canvas.onDrop = $.proxy(scope.editor.canvas.onDrop, canvas);

            var reader = new draw2d.io.json.Reader();
            reader.unmarshal(canvas, scope.jsonDocument1);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is a graphic showing the result:  The top graphic is the expected result. Notice that the box around the text is incorrectly sized and in the wrong place.

[image]

In addition to the formatting issues (text not correctly located and the box not sized correctly), the label cannot be selected and moved like the same label outside the accordion.

I am guessing that the draw2d library and the ui-bootstrap-tpls for the according (and perhaps other templates) conflict in someway either in attribute naming and/or css.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, it seems that the issue revolves around SVG's function `getBBox` (Get Bound Box).  The object is being created to fast.  Thus an injection of a short timeout, in this case 20ms, did the trick.

Changing

```
reader.unmarshal(canvas, scope.jsonDocument1);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){reader.unmarshal(canvas, scope.jsonDocument1);}, 0 );
```

did the trick.

WELL ---- WRONG (Or not completely right)

After getting some sleep, it turns out the `setTimeout` (or the angularjs `$timeout`) function only 'fixes' this issue **IF** `is-open="true"` is set on the accordion.  If not set or if it is on another accordion, then the fix fails.

It seems that the Accordion must be open **AND** the timeout used for the text label to be correctly rendered.

More research to come.......

Well the answer (from the Draw2d Developer http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/) is that `getBBox` will not function correctly on a text element until the element is in the DOM and visible.

So I added the modified the `<uib-accoridion-group>` header to:

```
<uib-accordion-group heading="The Chart" 
    ng-init="status = {isOpen: false}" is-open="status.isOpen">
```

I also added an `ng-if` to the inner div creating the graphic.  This causes the DOM to create the div when the accordion is opened.

```
<div ng-if="status.isOpen" id="canvas2" draw2d-canvas></div>
```

Like magic.

Comment: thank you same problem with bootstrap modal, solved adding the draw code inside $('#modal-container').on('shown', function () {